# When is it worth it to use the Sharpshooter -5/+10?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, optimization

I took the Sharpshooter feat at level one, as a variant human.

Let's say I have a hit bonus of *ATK_MOD* and I do on average *AVG_DMG* damage. Based on the perceived enemy's *AC*, when is it worth it to use the sharpshooter's -5/+10 feature?